# Laravel Mix: Adding a basic second file doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mix

Added the bottom 2 lines to my Webpack file, now it looks like this:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.js('vendor/redbastie/laravel-admin-pro/resources/js/laravel-admin-pro.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('vendor/redbastie/laravel-admin-pro/resources/sass/laravel-admin-pro.scss', 'public/css');
```

It's creating laravel-admin-pro.js, but not laravel-admin-pro.css.